# SNMP trap for MarkLogic

Tags: alert, marklogic, snmp, marklogic-9, snmp-trap

We are planning to use SNMP traps to monitor alerts using Netcool on MarkLogic linux servers.

How can we configure SNMP traps for alerting purpose in MarkLogic?

Example alerts:

- To monitor node health
- node status
- log monitoring for error/exceptions etc

Comment: Potential duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070877/how-to-configure-snmp-traps-in-a-marklogic-server

Comment: Suggestion would be helpful . Thanks!